# Incorrect syntax near '+'. when aliasing columns

Tags: sql

I keep getting an error when setting aliases on my columns

> Incorrect syntax near '+'.

```
select 
    m.MemberNumber as memno,
    rtrim(m.MemberFirstName) as namefirst + ' ' + RTRIM(m.MemberLastName) as namelast,
    m.MemberAddressLine1 as address + ', ' + m.MemberCity as city + ', ' + m.StateID as state + ', ' + m.MemberZip as zip,
    convert(nvarchar(20), m.MemberDOB, 101),
    m.MemberHomePhone as phonenumber,
    m.MemberEmail as emailaccount   
from LegacyMember m
```

I need to alias my columns as shown but not sure how to change it so it works without throwing an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have one alias for the concatenated value(s):

```
trim(m.MemberFirstName) + ' ' + RTRIM(m.MemberLastName) as FullName
```

If you need two separate values, it needs to be like this:

```
trim(m.MemberFirstName) as Namefirst
, RTRIM(m.MemberLastName) as Namelast
```

Comment: I can't because the code that is using this is expecting to use the aliases, so I need to be able to set the columns individually

Comment: @Chris:it won't work like that,when you concatenate,output will be a single column

Comment: Your select statement is returning one value by concatenating the two columns together.  If you need them individually, you need to select them individually.  The + is taking the two values together and turning them into a single value.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not mentioned what is expected output and how you actually want to see in output, here are two suggestion I can give

```
  select 
        m.MemberNumber as memno,
        rtrim(m.MemberFirstName)  + ' ' + RTRIM(m.MemberLastName) as FullName,
        m.MemberAddressLine1  + ', ' + m.MemberCity  + ', ' + m.StateID + ', ' + m.MemberZip as FullAddress,
        convert(nvarchar(20), m.MemberDOB, 101) as DateOfBirth,
        m.MemberHomePhone as phonenumber,
        m.MemberEmail as emailaccount   
    from LegacyMember m
```

or you can try this which nothing but the same

```
select tab1.namefirst + ' ' + tab1.namelast as "full Name",
       tab1.address + ' ' + tab1.city + ' ' + tab1.state + ' ' +  tab1.zip as "Full address",
       tab1.DateOfBirth as "Date of Birth",
       tab1.phonenumber as "Phone Number",
       tab1.emailaccount as "email Address" 
 from(
select 
    m.MemberNumber as memno,
    rtrim(m.MemberFirstName) as namefirst , RTRIM(m.MemberLastName) as namelast,
    m.MemberAddressLine1 as address , m.MemberCity as city , m.StateID as state , m.MemberZip as zip,
    convert(nvarchar(20), m.MemberDOB, 101) as DateOfBirth,
    m.MemberHomePhone as phonenumber,
    m.MemberEmail as emailaccount   
from LegacyMember m) tab1
```